# Angular 13 on refresh page not found showing

Tags: angular

I have 2 issues in angular 13. I'm new to angular, so I don't know how can I solve this.

**Question1:**
I'm building a website in angular 13, I have completed my work. when I deploy the website to my server
it's working, but when I refresh the page, the page is not found display
my route code

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'form', 
    component: FormComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', 
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
```

I don't want to use the hash method, because the URL does not look nice
is there any way to resolve this issue?
Currently, I'm hosting this website on a hostinger server.
in the future will host in azure cloud.

**Question2:**
When I build my project and upload it to the server, the screen show blank. but when I put (.)Dot before hash in index.html base URL, then its works

```
 <base href="./" />
```

Please guide me on how it happened, and how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, I guess you need to add one slash before to home in redirectTo might be it can resolve your issue.

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, <=== here in redirect it changes rest will be same.

 { path: 'home', component : HomeComponent },
```

About your 2nd question, you can dynamically set the base href in angular like the below example.

```
export function setBaseHrefDyanmic() {
let basePath: string = 'my-website' || ''; 
return '/' + basePath;
};
```

You can create the above new function in your **app.module.ts** file and add this into the **providers** array of app.module.ts file like below.

```
providers:[{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: setBaseHrefDyanmic}]
```

Comment: I tried /home but it is not working.
currently, manage to resolve this issue using .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server config file or .htaccess file

For example, If you are using Nginx server then pretty simple.

Edit you config file with

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_domain

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Hope this will help ;)